# Custom CSS for Facebook

Tags: css, ajax, facebook

Is it possible to make a wrapper-website that will display official Facebook page with my CSS? It should be something anyone can access for their FB profile without my page storing any information.

Please no FF plugins and similar!

I know that AJAX can not load page from another domain, but maybe something else... 
Maybe load it in iFrame and inject my css in there somehow???

Also, would that be legal?

Comment: my guess is that mark zuckerberg wouldn't be a huge fan of your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** load facebook through an iframe
You **can't** load your own CSS inside of that iframe

It's limitations of iframes and how HTML works